# how to change ReadWriteTimeout for powershell Invoke-WebRequest or Invoke-RestMethod?

Tags: powershell

We are trying to download search results from Splunk using the below mentioned Rest API endpoint through PowerShell Invoke-RestMethod and Invoke-WebRequest methods(both work). But some of our searches run for longer than 5 minutes due to which no data is returned to be written into a local file by Powershell's Invoke-RestMethod and Invoke-WebRequest methods and hence requests are timed out exactly after 5 mintues. We want to increase the ReadWriteTimeout mentioned on https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.readwritetimeout(v=vs.110).aspx page for Powershell's Invoke-RestMethod and Invoke-WebRequest methods, is it possible?

**Splunk Rest API Endpoint:**
 https://${server}:port/services/search/jobs/export

NOTE:- This Splunk endpoint starts streaming results after completing the search only.

Many might suggest to use another CURL client for making this Rest API call, we have already tried that and it's working since other clients like curl in Cygwin don't have the default 5 minute ReadWriteTimeout.

Answer (score 1):

No, but you can directly use the HttpWebRequest object you referenced instead.

I would recommend writing your own function `Invoke-MyRestMethod` that uses that class with parameters for R/W timeout and anything else you need.

Answer (score 0):

The [MSDN page on Invoke-WebRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/Invoke-WebRequest) indicates that there's a `-TimeoutSec` parameter that takes an `int32`. It appears that [Invoke-RestMethod](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.utility/invoke-restmethod) supports the same parameter.

Comment: It's different from ReadWriteTimeout.

Comment: @user6539841 - I assume, then, that you've tried it, setting a higher-than-300 timeout, and it still failed after 300 seconds (5 minutes)?

Comment: Yes, we have and it failed every time because it has a completely different significance. We have another search that runs just for 2 minutes but generates too much data hence the download takes around 30 minutes and the REST API call stays connected, there is no timeout in this case. But, the search that we are having issues with runs for 15 minutes straight and since the data streaming doesn't start till first 5 minutes , we encounter the ReadWriteTimeout which is a default for Powershell. I tried the same REST call with curl on cygwin and it ran fine for searches that take longer than 5 min

Comment: There is no timeout even during 30 minute download because the default value for -TimeoutSec in PowerShell is indefinite.